# jQuery on() Is Not Working

Tags: jquery, html

I am dynamically generating buttons on my site. To detect the `click` state of these elements, i believe you need to use jQuery's `on()`. I have tried the following but it does not seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$('.press').on('click', function() {
    alert('clicked'); //Does not trigger on dynamic elements
});
```

When you view my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GBRaY/1/), notice that clicking on the Dynamically Generated Buttons do not produce a result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want to delegate event handling, the selector goes on the element that will *contain* the dynamic elements (all the way up to `document`), and the second argument of `.on` is the selector: [see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.press', function () { ...
```

I suggest trying to have as specific a selector as possible when using delegation so that a minimal amount of traversal is required.  It usually doesn't make a huge difference, though.

Answer (score 3):

For dynamically generated elements you would need to use event delegation. The .on() needs to be applied to a parent element to do the delegation

Answer (score 2):

**Delegate the event**

```
$('body').on('click','.press', function() {
    alert('clicked'); // now it triggers on dynamic elements
});
```

You can replace the body with a `static parent container`..

Your approach will not work as the element is still `not available in the DOM` when you attach the event.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GBRaY/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$(document).on('click', ".press", function() {
    alert('clicked'); 
});
```

`$('.press')` finds all the elements currently in the document and binds the event on them, so it won't work on elements that you add later because they didn't exist at the time to be selected.

`$(document)` selects the `document`, which always exists anywhere and everywhere, and binds the event to it. It then filters `.press`, so that only elements that match `.press` will actually call the callback.

Note that you should select a parent element that's a common parent of the `.press` elements and exists at the time, rather than using `document`.